Nest.js relations change from one-to-many to one-to-one
For now I have project with two entities: Account and Profile, with relation one-to-many - one account can have multiple profiles. For now I have several instances of accounts and profiles, some of accounts have several profiles.
I want to know what would happen with those profiles, which are bounded to same account if I change relation to bidirectional one-to-one.
UPD:
I changed, and for some reason all profiles are present and bounded to account. I was expecting, that there will be left only one profile to one account.
Please explain why :(

Changing the relation decorator in TypeORM from one-to-many to one-to-one doesn't automatically modify existing data or enforce the new relationship constraint. That's why all your profiles remained and are still bound to their accounts after the change. To properly implement the one-to-one relationship, you'll need to manually update your database schema, clean up existing data, and potentially add constraints to ensure future data integrity.

Typeorm is capable of generating migration automatically for your tables schema based on the entities and the current state of your database shcema, but as @Dmytro metioned, it does not manipulate your data automatically to match the schema. In this situation that you have already data in your database, you should write a custom migration by hand to fix the data first and then get help from typeorm to generate an new migration for data schema and change the foreign key constraints. You can achieve this with creating a blank migration file with typeorm and write raw query in it:
typeorm migration:create ./path-to-migrations-dir/refactor-profile-account
For example, you maybe want write a query that only holds the oldest profile created for an accounts so only one profile remains for an account:
await queryRunner.query(`
  UPDATE account a
  SET profile_id = (
    SELECT p.id
    FROM profile p
    WHERE p.account_id = a.id
    ORDER BY p.created_at ASC
    LIMIT 1
  )`
);

And then cleaning spare profiles:
await queryRunner.query(`
  DELETE FROM profile
  WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT profile_id FROM account)`
);

